How to combine mouseenter and mouseleave function with ajax
Is it possible to cleanly combine this function.
I am using mouseenter function to show my ajax page content and hide it with mouseleave
$(function() {
    $("#card_client").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#results").load("data/show_card.php");
        $("#results").show();
    });

     $("#card_client").mouseleave(function(){
        $("#results").hide();
    });
});


What's wrong with what you have?

Use .hover() to combine them into one call:
$(function() {
    $("#card_client").hover(function(){
        $("#results").load("data/show_card.php").show();
    }), function(){
        $("#results").hide();
    });
});

The first function is executed when you start hovering, the second when you stop.

Now when I hover over the data displayed by "#results" the display flashes.
I would like it to stay fixed
$("#tablesForm tr").hover(
  function() {
    var idCard = $(this).attr("id");
    if (idCard > 0) {
    $("#results").load("data/show_card.php?mode=client&id="+idCard).show();
  }
}, function() {
  $("#results").hide();
});

